# Pan gesture recognizer selector won't work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, selector

In a SpriteKit game, I am trying to create a UIPanGestureRecognizer without using Interface Builder, so in the `didMoveToView` method of my `SKScene`, I wrote this :

```
let panGestureRecogniser = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: "didPan:")
view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecogniser)
```

Still in my SKScene class, I wrote this function :

```
func didPan(sender:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        println("Panned")
    }
```

My issue is that when I run my app, and when I pan on the screen, this error in thrown :

```
2015-05-12 19:28:01.955 Game[7342:2394353] -[SKView didPan:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154520690
```

**I don't understand what's wrong, I have tried to move the function in both my view controller and app delegate, but it doesn't seem to make any difference...**

Comment: Target should be the scene, not the view. Target is where the action resides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
let panGestureRecogniser = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: "didPan:")
```

To

```
let panGestureRecogniser = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didPan:")
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot ! I don't understand what has changed exactly ? Why does it work now ?

Comment: target: view has been changed to target:self.

Comment: Yes I do understand that, but I thought target would only change what the gesture recognizer tracks, I don't understand why it has fixed the selector error ?

Comment: A view cannot be set as target because a view cannot perform actions. It is only there to display things. Actions are performed in controllers. For more information read MVC design pattern.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't realised that target was the target of the sector and not of the gesture recogniser